# How to use English, Russian and Spanish languages in windows console

Tags: c, windows

I tried to google this problem, but didn't find a clear answer. I'm writing a program for myself to practice English and Spanish languages. It´s simple, I have my vocabulary in word, so I created a code, randomly pick a word, show in monitor, second "Enter" will show translation in other language. For now I did it only English -> Spanish. But in general I would like to do it Russia -> English plus Spanish. The problem is that different languages doesn't show up properly in Windows console. I need to have Russian cyrylica, Spanish special symbols, like ñ and English transcription of words. I use NetBeans IDE, its own console doesn't process very well scanf function, so I have to use windows console instead.
Is there any way to do this?
Here is the code. I use random generated symbols then I use additional code to exclude repeated numbers. It's just a prototype, the original vocabulary has a couple of thousands of words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>


#define WORDS 25
void func_words(int rnd);

int main(void) {

    system("COLOR B0");
    srand((time)(NULL));
    char ch;
    int random;
    int count=0;
    int rand_array[1000];
    int MATCH;
    printf("\nPress Enter to continue:");

    while(scanf("%c",&ch)&&ch=='\n')
    {

        for(int i=0;random=rand()%WORDS+1;i++)
        {
            MATCH=0;
            rand_array[i]=random;

            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {

                if(random==rand_array[j])
                    MATCH++;
            }

            if(MATCH!=0)
            continue;
        func_words(random);
        count++;
        printf("\n%i\n",count);
        if(count==WORDS)
            break;
        }

        printf("\nFINISH!\n");

    }



    return 0;
}

void func_words(int rnd)
{
    char ch2;
    char *ar[WORDS][2]={
    {"Costumbre","Habbit, bad habbit"},
    {"Comer", "Eat, Eating, Meal"},
    {"Beber", "Drink, you drink too much"},
    {"Costumbre", "Habit, annoying habit"},
    {"referirse", "Refer"},
    {"el verbo", "Verb"},
    {"Aplicar, emplear", "Apply, We applied to the authorities for assistance. To apply the new method"},
    {"oración", "Sentence, make up a sentence, affirmative sentence"},
    {"piel", "Skin, leather"},
    {"las mejillas", "Cheek"},
    {"bigote", "Moustache, Whisker"},
    {"barba", "beard"},
    {"las pestañas", "eyelash"},
    {" lengua", "language tongue"},
    {"  los órganos internos", "internals "},
    {"lung ", "los pulmones"},
    {"liver  ", "hígado"},
    {"riñones", "Kidney "},
    {"cuello", "neck "},
    {"hueso", "Bones "},
    {"músculo  musculatura", "muscle  "},
    {"nervio", "Nerves "},
    {"nervio", "breathe"},
    {"Reír /  risa", "laugh smile "},
    {"mentón", "chin "},
    {"las cejas", "eyebrow "},

    {"", ""},

    };

        printf("        %s",ar[rnd-1][0]);
        scanf("%c",&ch2);
        printf("\n");
        printf("        %s",ar[rnd-1][1]);
        printf("\n---------------------------\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem relate with character codification: As you know, computers work with binary, or in general numbers, not with letters. Thus, a `char` is just a type of 1-byte integer

```
char letter = '0'; // letter contain 48
```

There are several standards about mapping those numbers to a glyph (letter) and your console must understand this standard for being able to render your standard output correctly.

On of the first character codification standard is ASCII, which unfortunately only understand english characters, then came Latin, and other adaptions to get most of the european sets.

Finally, Unicode is being accepted because it allows most of the characters world-wide, including about 120000 code points. This obviously requires several bytes per character, which triggered UTF8, UTF16, etc. for handling Unicode over computer strings.

---

Answering your question, to display complex characters set you need:

1) To encode your text into a standard which accept those characters (e.g. UTF8) For this purpose, you may implement your own standards, or use one of the many libraries available online.

2) Use a console which understand UTF8. Not sure about the default console of windows.

---

Note that C does not ensure to have special characters support in it, so `ñ` in your code could be rejected. The alternative is an escape sequence of 2 to several bytes like `'\241'` matching the target encoding.

Comment: *"C is not supposed to have special characters in it"* Not entirely true. C standard mentions *extended character set*, which allows special characters. In practice, compilers usually support characters outside of *basic character set* in comments or string literals.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, I hope my rewording fit better the reality.

Comment: and 3) a font that can display such characters. Not all fonts do, and I think the default windows console font can't. Regarding 2) windows console can understand UTF8, but it needs to be specified with `chcp`

Comment: @bolov, the console's implementation of codepage 65001 is too buggy -- e.g. even in Windows 10 it doesn't allow reading non-ASCII characters because of encoding bugs in the console host process, conhost.exe. The only reliable way to read and write Unicode to the console is via the wide-character console API, e.g. `ReadConsoleW` and `WriteConsoleW`. This can be enabled in the C runtime via `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` and then using wide-character standard I/O functions such as `wprintf`.